# How make my Facebook PAGE feed appear on my personal website?

Tags: facebook, web, facebook-page, facebook-feed

I have a Facebook "fan page" for my acting career (I mean a page that I created within my personal FB account) I want to make the feed from this page appear on my personal website as a "news feed" for publicity reasons. My website developer tool has a "custom HTML" option that has allowed me to make my Twitter feed appear on the webpage, but I want to use my Facebook page instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you are searching for is the **[Like Box](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/)** which has option to display your Page's stream on your website. Features about the like box (Quoting from documentation)

- See how many people like the Page, and which of their friends like it, too.
- Read recent posts from the Page.
- Like the Page with one click, without needing to visit the Page.

Answer (score 0):

Like box is a widget shown in an iframe. For users who want a full fledged solution that works on any device -

Famax is a plugin that will pull out your page posts, what people are posting on your page, your page albums etc.

http://www.codehandling.com/2015/03/famax-40-complete-facebook-fanpage.html